# mount directory still showing data after remove USB manually

Tags: linux, centos, backup, mount, unmount

i'm working on linux centos 7.4,where i mounting USB device with '/dev/sdxn'.

mounted directory present in '/storage/mount_usb'(ex:inside one file is present like movie.mp4).

if i manually unplugged (without unmounting it) and i check command 'lsblk' their '/dev/sdxn' is not present, so here looks like ok for me.

but when i run command 'll /storage/mount_usb/movie.mp4' then it's still showing some of the data and we can also able to open file in read mode(using open,fopen systemcall).

command 'll /storage/mount_usb/movie.mp4 '.
i.e -rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 1506417406 Jan 29 16:17 /storage/mount_usb/movie.mp4

but when i run command 'll /storage/mount_usb'.
i.e- ls: reading directory /storage/mount_usb: Input/output error total 0

and if i use opendir("/storage/mount_usb") then it will also open successfully and not return any error code.

i'm not able to understand why data is still showing after unplugged USB.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

I assume 'll' is 'ls -l'

opendir("/storage/mount_usb") will work since the directory exists even if nothing is mounted on it.

'll /storage/mount_usb/movie.mp4 ' works if the required data is still in file system caches.

'll /storage/mount_usb' does not work since you want to list all files in the directory. To do this, the file system tries to access the device which you have unplugged without telling the file system.

Comment: how can i  clear file system caches to get proper information

Comment: You should unmount the device before unplugging it. If you don't unmount file systems before unpluggin them you risk corrupting the files

Comment: This command will clear directory entries and inodes 'sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'